# Sort output in bash script by number of occurances

Tags: bash, sorting

So I have a text being outputted that has http status codes in one column and an ip adress in the other. I wan't to sort this by number of occurances so that

```
1 2 1 3 4 5 4 4
```

Looks like

```
4 4 4 1 1 2 3 5
```

This is for the second column of status codes, the ip adresses dont need to be sorted in any particular order

Since 4 is the most common one it should be first and then 1 and so forth.

However all that I can find is how to use `uniq` for example in order to count the occurances, thereby removing duplicates and prefixing a number to each row.

The regular `sort` command does not support this as far as i can tell as well.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can still use `sort | uniq -c`, then interpret the number of occurrences by printing the number the given times by looping:

```
tr ' ' '\n' < file \
| sort | uniq -c | sort -k1,1nr -k2n \
| while read times status ; do
    for i in $(seq 1 $times); do
        printf '%s ' $status
    done
done
```

Comment: Is this possible to use with two columns? I should have mentioned that there's x amount of ip adresses in the first column and then the status code in the other. I assume that this only works with one column

Comment: @Krysvac: Feel free to ask a new question.